# Fixed-point iteration and continuity of parameters

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ a compact set and $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Consider a continuous function $f\colon X\times A\to X$ and construct a fixed-point iteration as follows
$$
x_{k+1}=f(x_k,a),\quad x_0\in X, a \in A.\quad (\star)
$$

> **My question**: If $(\star)$ admits a unique fixed point, denoted by $\mathrm{Fix}(f_a)$, for all $a\in A$, can we conclude that $\mathrm{Fix}(f_a)$ is a continuous function of $a$? What can be said in case $(\star)$ admits a *set* of fixed points for all $a\in A$?

Thanks for your help.

*Comments.* This question is different from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700725/continuity-of-fixed-point). Indeed, here $f$ is not assumed to be contractive.

Comment: Which approach have you looked at to show the continuity from the parameter $a$ to the fixed points so far?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is metric (with metric $d_X$), and consider the following parameterized family of optimization problems:
$$
\max_{x \in X} \, -d_X\big(x, f(x,a)\big) \tag{$\ast$}
$$
By construction, $d_X\big(x, f(x,a)\big)$ is continuous in $(x,a)$, and given $X$ is compact, it is straightforward to verify the other conditions of [Berge's Theorem of the Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem).

Consider the argmax correspondence, i.e. the possibly set-valued mapping $\phi: A \rightrightarrows X$ defined via $a \mapsto \{x \in X : f(x,a) =x\}$.  By Berge, we obtain that $\phi$ is [upper hemicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#Upper_hemicontinuity) as a correspondence.

Any upper hemicontinuous correspondence that additionally is singleton-valued is a continuous function. Thus, if each $f(\cdot, a)$ admits a unique fixed point, $\phi$ is a continuous function. If some $f(\cdot, a)$ admit more than one fixed point, $\phi$ will not be singleton-valued, but will instead be upper hemicontinuous as a correspondence (here, equivalent to having a closed graph in $A \times X$).

Note nothing in this requires these fixed points to be attracting under the specified dynamics.